# How to scale an image to the full size on a div after the image has been dragged and dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am wondering if it's possible to automatically scale (make larger) an image to the full size of a div after the image has been dragged and dropped onto that div, using JS / jQuery?

*Note the image will not disappear from it's original position, rather a copy of that image will be dragged and dropped into the div (so it's really the copy I need to scale).

I have the current code to drag and dropcopy the image (see below), but I don't know if auto scaling it is possible and if so, how... Thanks in advance!

```
    <html>
    <img id="drag1" src="image.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div id="dropBox" ondrop="dropcopy(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </html>


    <style>
    #drag1{width:100px;height:50px;}
    #dropBox{width:500px;height:250px;}
    </style>


    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    function dropcopy(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
        var original = document.getElementById(data);
        copyimg.src = original.src;
        ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Creating a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery when you can use CSS?

```
img{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `"text"` for `"Text"` at
`ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");` , `data` for `original.src` at `copyimg.src = data;` , setting `style` property of `#dropBox img` `width`  calling `window.getComputedStyle()` on `ev.target`

```html
<html>
<img id="drag1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" 
     draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<div id="dropBox" 
     ondrop="dropcopy(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<style>
  #drag1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #dropBox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px dotted #000
  }
</style>
<script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

  function dropcopy(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyimg = document.createElement("img")
    copyimg.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(ev.target)
                          .getPropertyValue("width");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    copyimg.src = data;
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
  }
</script>

</html>
```